# Mobile UI in iPad in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, ui, design, ipad

I just came to notice that in iPad devices, Salesforce1 app is reflecting the mobile design of the app!

I'm specifically asking it because, in the Chrome simulator, it's showing the table layout itself when Opportunity tab is taken.

PFB, the screenshots for reference.

1. **Salesforce1_PortraitView_1 | iPad** :- 
   [image: Salesforce1_PortraitView_1]
2. **Salesforce1_PortraitView_2 | iPad** :-
   [image: Salesforce1_PortraitView_2]
3. **Salesforce1_LandscapeView_1 | iPad** :- 
   [image: Salesforce1_LandscapeView_1]
4. **Salesforce1_Chrome_Simulator_Portrait | iPad** :- 
   [image: Salesforce1_Chrome_Simulator_Portrait]
5. **Salesforce1_Chrome_Simulator_Landscape | iPad** :-
   [image: Salesforce1_Chrome_Simulator_Landscape]

> iOS 10.3.1 Salesforce1 v13.1 Build #3032251

**Is this an issue or is it that they've updated the Salesforce1 design in iPad devices(and not being reflected in the simulator)?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you find anything about this yet?  I'm finding that SF is forcing either Classic or Salesforce1 Web when using Safari on an iPad.

In Chrome, I can request the Desktop Version, and it allows me to access Lightning Experience, but Safari will not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you opted for the "**new Salesforce mobile app tablet experience**" as per this Salesforce [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=salesforce_app_ipad_considerations.htm&type=5).

I think in Simulator it is showing the new Salesforce mobile app tablet experience where as in your device it is showing the old experience.

*Upgrading to the New Salesforce Mobile App*

During the new Salesforce mobile app pilot and in Winter '20, orgs that opted in to the new Salesforce mobile app also got the new Salesforce mobile app tablet experience. Now, admins who opted in can choose whether all users in the org get the new tablet experience or the previous tablet experience. Go to Setup, enter `QuickStart` in the Quick Find box, then select **New Salesforce Mobile App Quickstart**. Look for the New Salesforce Mobile App for Tablet section.

If you didn’t opt in to the new Salesforce mobile app, all users in your org see the previous Salesforce mobile app tablet experience.